# i'am having trouble with pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  filter: opacity(1);
  color: #eee;
}

#about::before {
  background: url(/img/backgroud1.svg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  filter: opacity(0.01);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="about">
        <h1>hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me why my background image is not displayed
I want my heading to be on top of a background image.

Answer (score 0):

- A `::before` psuedo-element won't display *anything* if it doesn't have any `content` so give it some content
- `height` and `width` do nothing on an element which is `display: inline` which `::before` is by default
- With an opacity as low as you are setting, it will be as good as invisible. Increase the opacity so you can see it.
- You need to absolutely position the element (with a positioned container to anchor it) if you want the text to be on top of the image

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  filter: opacity(1);
  color: #eee;
}

#about {
    position: relative;
}

#about::before {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200);
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  filter: opacity(0.50);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="about">
        <h1>hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should put string marks in the url protion

```
 background: url("/img/backgroud1.svg");
```

Comment: There are no special characters in that URL which would require quoting.